# Can't decode JSON string in php

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON string, i try to decode with php json_decode but $postarray
is always NULL, can't work out why this is?

Running on Debian 5.0 Linux
php Client API version => 5.0.51a
Json version 1.2.1

```
 $json = '{\"json\":[{\"username\":\"1062576\",\"accountId\":\"45656565\"}]}';

 $postarray = json_decode($json);
 print_r($postarray);
```

Thanks

Comment: The backslashes are making that JSON string invalid. You don't have to escape doublequotes within a single-quoted string, or vice versa. You only have to escape quotes when the internal quotes are the same as the enclosing quotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason to escape double quotes (`\"`) in a string, is if the string is double quoted.

Since you are escaping the double quotes, you should double (not single) quote your string, like this:

```
<?php
 $json = "{\"json\":[{\"username\":\"1062576\",\"accountId\":\"45656565\"}]}";

 $postarray = json_decode($json);
 print_r($postarray);
?>
```

[**Live Example**](http://pajtai.codepad.org/NZUdWHkG)

If you do want to single quote your string, then [**don't escape the double quotes**](http://pajtai.codepad.org/LQhLXJT7), or use [**stripslashes()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) like Andrei suggested.

You can read about [**the four ways to specify a string in PHP, and the differences among them, here**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
<?php
$json = stripslashes('{\"json\":[{\"username\":\"1062576\",\"accountId\":\"45656565\"}]}');

$postarray = json_decode($json);
print_r($postarray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should enclose it in double quotes.

Comment: Well, that will bypass the problem, but that isn't the problem.  The problem is that there are un-necessary backslashes (which I'm guessing are being added by [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc)...  Even if not, that doesn't help understand why it isn't working...

Comment: @BoltClock Enclosing it with double quotes will make the "\" actually escape the double quotes inside the json string, therefore making it valid.

Comment: The single quotes make it stop working. Enclosing it in double quotes and it works.

Comment: +1 from me, as it fixes the problem. @Dennis: You might explain why he should do that or what he could do instead (like replacing the backslashes).

Comment: @ Denniss, you don't deserve the vote-down because you solved it.+1 from me.

Comment: @Kau-Boy:  That's exactly why I did the -1.  Not because this doesn't work, but because it doesn't fix the problem.  Obviously the backslashes are there for a reason.  The quesiton is what is that reason?  Is it because of `magic_quotes`?  Is it because the data was mis-escaped when being put into a database?  Is it because `addslashes` was called right before?  Sure, double quotes is the answer to the exact question given.  However, it's not a general solution, and may not solve the OP's problem (since I have a feeling the string given was just a generalization of a bigger problem)...

Comment: @ircmaxell: Usually when you recive JSON data from a request, the quotes are escaped. If you know about that useing double qoutes is a valid solution, even though stripslashes is a better one.

Comment: Huh?  How is using double quotes a valid solution?  The incomming JSON would be stored in a variable.  So where do the dobule quotes go (since there's no string parsing going on which requires the escaped `"` characters as in the example provided)...

Answer (score 1):

The string will not be parsed because it is enclosed in single quotes, so the backslashes are literal.  If you remove them, use stripslashes, or enclose the string in double quotes, you should have no problems.