# JSON not decoding correctly in php

Tags: php, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't decode JSON string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586401/cant-decode-json-string-in-php)

I'm at my wits end here, and I can't figure it out.
My code was working correctly locally (using xamp) but now it won't work.

When I run this code:

```
echo "passed in parameter" . $_POST["jsoned"];
$unjasoned = json_decode("[\"23\",[],[[\"a@a.a\",\"2011-01-08\"]]]");
die("\ntype\n\t". gettype($unjasoned) . "\n\n\nAmount\n\t" . $unjasoned[0]);
```

I get:

```
passed in parameter[\"23\",[],[[\"a@a.a\",\"2011-01-08\"]]]
type
    array


Amount
    23
```

Which is **exactly** what i want

However the problem happens when I use the passed variable in `$_POST["jsoned"]` which is you see in the result above is obviously exactly the same as what im manually inserting here.

so if i do this instead (same exact input):

```
echo "passed in parameter" . $_POST["jsoned"];
$unjasoned  = json_decode($_POST["jsoned"]);
die("\ntype\n\t". gettype($unjasoned) . "\n\n\nAmount\n\t" . $unjasoned[0]);
```

I get:

```
passed in parameter[\"23\",[],[[\"a@a.a\",\"2011-01-08\"]]]
type
    NULL


Amount
```

so...... WHAT THE HELL IS HAPPENING?! PLEASE if you have any hints share them with me, ill be eternally thankful.

ps. my server runs php version 5.2.13

Comment: feed your $_POST["jsoned"] to stripslashes() first

Comment: if you try usin simple quotes ' around your string test in the 1st example version you'll maybe get a difference, no? do a print_r($_POST["jsoned"]) so we can see the real debug content.

Comment: I swear I wasn't being lazy, I actually searched for about an hour and then gave up.

Comment: ps.  Col. Shrapnel your striplashes() was invaluable. Thanks a lot I didn't know that even existed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answered already here [Can't decode JSON string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586401/cant-decode-json-string-in-php)

Comment: should have been a comment or at least a CW, since we do not get upvotes for finding duplicates

Comment: @Shrapnel You're awfully sarcastic these days... And +1 for finding the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks again guys, and as i mentioned before I really was searching for over an hour. I just didn't know what I was searching for I guess. Cheers

Comment: @Gordon we must have been typing at the same time. sorry for that. :) Up-votes don't harm. Only if there was a feature to merge repeated questions I would have done that.

Comment: @Nishant Moderators can merge questions. Just flag the question and ask for it. And yes, earning upvotes for providing a possible duplicate does harm. Technically you are cheating.

Comment: @Gordon I didn't know that. OK, learned that, will keep in mind. Ah, don't be so hardcore... I agree I should've commented instead of answering and flagged as well. But for god sake, why so serious? Cheating, plagiarism... it's like pointing to a previously answered page was the most hideous thing one can do over weekend. Really sorry that I made person unhappy by typing a URL as answer instead of comment which he found the same time as I did.

Comment: @Nishant You are misunderstanding what I am trying to say. This is not about who provided the duplicate first. You found it. I didnt even look for one. You do not have the reputation to closevote yet, so I did that for you. I have no problem whatsoever with you finding a duplicate. Most people are too lazy for it. Kudos for doing so. All I am saying is, if you cannot closevote yet, but know it's a duplicate, either put it as a comment or make your answer CW because that's the closest to the real thing you are supposed to do.

Comment: @Gordon thanks. I got your point.

Answer (score 0):

The string in the post has `\"` instead of `"`.

When you write the string yourself as a literal you have to write `\"` because you're inside double quotes, but in the resulting string you'll only get a `"`.

Try this debug to see the difference:

```
echo $_POST["jsoned"], PHP_EOL;
echo "[\"23\",[],[[\"a@a.a\",\"2011-01-08\"]]]";
```

Comment: I'd upvote you if i could but i don't have enough reputation. Eitherway thank's a lot for your answer